# how to return data to ajax from java Servlet

Tags: java, ajax, servlets

i have my ajax function as follows:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: "/myservlet",
  data: {
  objects: '2',
  dimension: '2',
  },
  success: function( data ) {
  console.log(data);
  alert(data);
  },
  error:function(data,status,er) {
    alert("error: "+data+" status: "+status+" er:"+er);
   }
 });
```

and i have my servlet to process the data sent to /myservlet. I read from the ajax tutorial which said the data in the success function is the data that ajax got from the server side. But i don't know how to set this data or return this data from doGet method in a Java servlet to the frontend. It seems doGet is a void method and cannot return any values, isn't it? I am a freshman in web development, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You can get the data from servlet by writing on `response.getWriter().write("");`.

Here is a simple servlet example.

```
@WebServlet(name = "MyServlet", urlPatterns = {"/myservlet"})
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        response.getWriter().write("Success Data");
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You no need to return any thing from the `doGet` method , infact you can not as it's void.

So what you need to do is get the `PrintWriter` object  from the response and write data to it and that will available in the success function .

Answer (score 0):

You might notice that the doGet() method has two parameters: HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse.

You use HttpServletRequest to get information about the request - any parameters, the calling client IP, the URL etc.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html

You use HttpServletResponse to populate the response. HttpServletResponse has a number of methods allowing you to set response headers and data.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html