# How do I print the successful statement in the if condition after getting values from an ajax call?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page import="java.net.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>    
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input").change(function(){
        var p1 = $('#password1').val();
        var p2 = $('#password2').val();
        var p3 = $('#password3').val();
        var p4 = $('#password4').val();

        $.post('http://localhost../mycode.jsp',
        {
            pass1 : p1,
            pass2 : p2,
            pass3 : p3,
            pass4 : p4,
        },
        function(data,status){
            console.log(data)
            alert("Status : "+ status);
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<%
String pw1,pw2,pw3,pw4;
pw1 = "1";
pw2 = "2";
pw3 = "3";
pw4 = "4";
out.println("<div id='password' style=' display: block; position: absolute; left: 30%;'>");
out.println("<h1 style=' position: absolute; top: -120%; left: 18%; font-family: Titillium Web;'>PASSWORD</h1>");
out.println("<form method='POST'>");
out.println("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type='number' id='password1' maxlength='1' max='9' style=' width: 1%; padding: 12px 12px; margin: 8px 0px; border: none; border-bottom: 2px solid red;'>");
out.println("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type='number' id='password2' maxlength='1' max='9' style=' width: 1%; padding: 12px 12px; margin: 8px 0px; border: none; border-bottom: 2px solid red;'>");
out.println("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type='number' id='password3' maxlength='1' max='9' style=' width: 1%; padding: 12px 12px; margin: 8px 0px; border: none; border-bottom: 2px solid red;'>");
out.println("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type='number' id='password4' maxlength='1' max='9' style=' width: 1%; padding: 12px 12px; margin: 8px 0px; border: none; border-bottom: 2px solid red;'>");
out.println("</form>");
out.println("</div>");

String ele1 = request.getParameter("pass1");
String ele2 = request.getParameter("pass2");
String ele3 = request.getParameter("pass3");
String ele4 = request.getParameter("pass4");

if((pw1.equals(ele1)) && (pw2.equals(ele2)) &&(pw3.equals(ele3)) && (pw4.equals(ele4)))
     out.println("Code Successful!!");
else
    out.println("Code Failed.");
%>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the basic code of what I am working with. I want to perform an action after the user form data is sent asynchronously to the server and server performs tasks. How do I update those if condition values whose value is set at runtime by the user.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to perform an action after the user form data is sent asynchronously to the server and server performs tasks.

Assuming we are sticking to Jquery ajax, *anything you want to do in response to an async request has to be done via callback function*.

In other words:

```
$.post('http://localhost../mycode.jsp',
// ... other arguments to ajax call
function(data,status){
// do stuff that requires waiting on async request HERE
});
```

Thats the only place where you know the request has completed with whatever status.

You can move the `if` logic into there or another one suggestion is to wrap up the logic you want executed into another smaller function. And then call that from inside the `$.post` callback.

Comment: So, I would have to pass the parameters pw1,pw2... to the callback function?

Comment: How do I pass the values of pw's to the ajax function?

Comment: Well, by the looks of the code you shared, those variables are in-scope of the ajax callback function. So in that case you could just reference them in the function body. If somehow they are not, you should be able to use a closure to get them in scope of the callback.

Comment: I am talking about the variables pw1, pw2, etc which are being generated on the server side in the <body> tag and are needed to be sent to the ajax callback function. I am guessing I need to send it back as response to the success function but I am not sure How to send it from jsp and receive it in ajax.

Comment: Ah, I had totally missed the JSP reference. My bad. Out of my wheelhouse, but it looks like by default jsp returns html to write to page? Out of curiosity I found some references that mite help w/ sending data to a callback: [how to return data to ajax from servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18479477/how-to-return-data-to-ajax-from-java-servlet) and [how to use servlets and ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4113258/2415751)